# speed up the zxing QR scanning time for android?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am using the Zxing library for scanning only `QRcode 39` in my application. thanks to `sean` for the wonderful work. It is working fine, But the problem is, It takes more time to scan. I am scanning with both front camera and rear camera.

I am using zxing project as library to my application.

With the help of cameraInfo API, I am finding the front camera index and passing through an intent to `ScanCard which extends CaptureActivity` --> `CameraManager`.

```
public class ScanCard extends CaptureActivity {

@Override
public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.handleDecode(rawResult, barcode);
    mScanResult = rawResult.getText().toString();
}
}
```

In the Camera Manager class, I changed accordingly to show the front facing camera for scanning as like below.

```
 public void openDriver(SurfaceHolder holder, int myCamera)
    throws IOException {

Camera theCamera = camera;

if (theCamera == null) {
    theCamera = Camera.open(myCamera);
    if (theCamera == null) {
        throw new IOException();
    }
    camera = theCamera;
}
theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

if (!initialized) {
    initialized = true;
    configManager.initFromCameraParameters(theCamera);
    if (requestedFramingRectWidth > 0 && requestedFramingRectHeight > 0) {
        setManualFramingRect(requestedFramingRectWidth,
                requestedFramingRectHeight);
        requestedFramingRectWidth = 0;
        requestedFramingRectHeight = 0;
    }
}
configManager.setDesiredCameraParameters(theCamera);
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
reverseImage = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_REVERSE_IMAGE,
        false);
 }
```

What should i do to make the scan more faster? Thanks for the help

When i surf around, I got this Nimbledroid. It's good to go with [NimbleDroid](http://www.nimbledroid.com/)?

Comment: What is "Qrcode 39". "Code 39"? It is not a "QR code". How "fast"? what about the original Barcode Scanner? You may have a bug in your app that is nothing to do with the library. zxing scans Code 39 in < 10ms.

Comment: @Sean Owen, I do agree that your original barcode scanner downloaded from google play scan this in less than 10 ms. the same thing happening for my application also if i use the rear camera. But in case of front camera, I am not getting results in less than 10 ms. I am using matricom [tablet](http://matricom.net/products/g-tab-quantum-10-1-quad-core-tablet/)

Comment: Front cameras don't scan well. Also, do not copy and paste our app; it's not permitted. https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/License-Questions

Answer (score -3):

https://github.com/zxing/zxing core folder is fair enough do deal with android. You don't need to use android-xxx projects.

If you want to scan codes faster, you should use ZBar library http://zbar.sourceforge.net/ but it is under GPL licence.

**EDIT**

```
int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
int[] pixels = new int[bitmapWidth * bitmapHeight];

bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmapWidth, 0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);
bitmap.recycle();
RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, pixels);
BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();

try {
    return reader.decode(binaryBitmap).toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // nothing happens - entry is just not available in this frame
}

return null;
```

bitmap is [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) object created from camera video Preview.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html) you got explanation how to set the camera preview.
In [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) object you should set [PreviewCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallback%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29) that gives you bytes that should be converted into Bitmap. Zxing has a nice api, but their android app is a crap - that is all you need.

HTH

PS. Put in the google "zbar android" - first link contains api for android shared on github...

Comment: i just Renamed the android zxing project and using that in my application. How can i deal alone with core.jar file? Is that enough to scan the QR code? If so, How could that be? would you please direct me to a working example. It seems that zbar doesn't have android sdk.

Comment: Thanks for kind words @Gaskoin but zbar has no Android app at all, and the issue is not 'scan speed' as the OP says.

Comment: So what is this site about - https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android ? Is this a porn site or you have a ban for google sites?


As far as I can see the author has a problem with scan speed and you are telling me that scan speed is not an issue ... !?

Answer (score -4):

Instead of adding all the packages of the zxing library, why don't you try adding zxing project as a library in your application.

Comment: thats what i did. I have only added the zxing project as my library to my application. I have edited the question.